# Create array of characters on heap instead of stack

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio, heap-memory

I need a character array to store the data of a file, and the file can have up to 30,000 characters in it. I tried doing this:

```c
char buf[30000]
```

But, this seemed like an easy way to accidentally cause a stack overflow or some other error. So, I tried using calloc like this:

```c
char* buf = calloc(30000, 1);
```

But Visual Studio told me something about dereferencing, so how would I do this?

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char  ch;
    char filename[256] = "";

    FILE* fp;

    printf("Enter name of a file you wish to see\n");
    gets(filename);

    fopen_s(&fp, filename, "r"); // read mode

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i = 0;
    char* buf = calloc(30000, 1);

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        buf[i];
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to be explicit about what "something about dereferencing" is.

Comment: When trying to add a character to it using `buf[i] = ___` is gives me `Dereferencing NULL pointer 'buf'`

Comment: You're going to need to give us a [mcve] for us to see what the problem is.

Comment: You probably have another `buf` variable that's shadowing this one.

Comment: @Finxx It means that you are compiling the program as a C++ program. Write char* buf = ( char * )calloc(30000, 1);

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That would cause a different error about a type mismatch.

Comment: Note that this is a warning from your IDE, not an error coming from the compiler.

Comment: `buf[i];` should be `buf[i] = ch;`

Comment: @Barmar Where is there type mismatch?

Comment: Assigning a `void*` to `char*` without a cast. @VladfromMoscow

Comment: C allows using calloc without casting its value

Comment: `char ch;` should be `int ch;`

Comment: @Finxx Right, that's why Vlad thinks the OP is compiling using C++.

Comment: Never, ever, use `gets()`.  It is not only deprecated in standard C, but actually *deleted*, and this because it is irretrievably unsafe.  `fgets()` is a safer alternative with similar behavior.

Comment: for some reason fgets didnt work. It works on linux and it is what I usually use, but for some reason it didn't work on windows

Comment: In complaining about "Dereferencing NULL pointer 'buf'", Visual Studio is presumably observing that you do not check whether `buf`'s value is null before using it.  `calloc()` will return a null pointer on failure, and it is the programmer's responsibility to check for that and take appropriate action if they want to be sure to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: Vague information like "something about dereferencing" and "for some reason it didn't work" will not be very useful in helping people understand and resolve your problem.  Please copy/paste the literal error messages, every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***ALWAYS*** check the result of a `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` call - they will return `NULL` if they cannot satisfy the request.  Based on your comment, the `calloc` call failed, so trying to access `buf[i]` is raising an error.

Add a check as follows:

```
char* buf = calloc(30000, 1);
if ( !buf )
{
  /**
   * calloc could not satisfy the request - bail out at this point.
   */
  fprintf( stderr, "memory allocation failed!\n" );
  fclose( fp );
  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

/**
 * You also need a check here to make sure you don't
 * read more characters than your array is sized to 
 * hold.  That should be easy enough to figure out. 
 */
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    buf[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear whether the OP's `calloc()` call *did* fail, *vs*. Visual Studio warning on the basis of static analysis that it *could* fail, in which case the program would exhibit UB.